# How to assign different number of threads to each functions using OpenMP

Tags: multithreading, for-loop, parallel-processing, openmp, sections

I have two functions, and a for-loop inside the second function.

```
fun1() {
    ...
}
fun2() {
    for(...) {
    }
}
```

Now i want to run `fun1` and `fun2` in parallel (i.e. each function using a single thread). And inside `fun2` i wish i can use `omp parallel for` to execute the for-loop.

I tried to implement it like this.

```
fun1() {
}

fun2() {
    #pragma omp for
    for() {
    }
}

int main() {
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp single
        {
            fun1();
        }
        fun2();
    {
}
```

But it would invoke `fun2` several times.

So is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a combination of OpenMP sections and nested parallelism:

In `main`:

```c
omp_set_nested(1);

#pragma omp parallel sections num_threads(2)
{
   #pragma omp section
   fun1();

   #pragma omp section
   fun2();
}
```

In `fun2`:

```c
#pragma omp parallel for
for (...)
{
}
```

To run your program with e.g. 8 threads, do something like this:

```
OMP_NUM_THREADS=8 OMP_THREAD_LIMIT=8 ./program
```

This way, the outer parallel region will execute with two threads and the nested parallel region in `fun2` will execute with seven threads. If `OMP_THREAD_LIMIT` is not set to 8 (or is unset), OpenMP will start eight threads for the nested region for nine threads in total, which might or might not be desirable.

Comment: Thank you very much. It helps a lot.